# Argument 'controllerLogin' is not a function, got undefined - AngularJs, Karma Testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm, karma-jasmine

Hello Fellow Genius Developers,

Currently i am learning AngularJs and doing some basic testing but keep on getting errors.
Please Please help me out with this. I have looked around for the answers but could not find anything. Your any help would be very much appreciated.

Below is the Error.

```
 `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'controllerLogin' is not a function, got undefined
```

I am using WebStrom IDE.

Here is my controllerLogin.js

'use strict';

```
var loginApp = angular.module('loginApp',[]);

(function() {

    //define this for the minification of javascripts
    var loginScope=['$scope'];
    var loginController = function($scope){
        $scope.hello = "Hello Galaxy";

    };

    loginController.$inject = loginScope;
    angular.module('loginApp').controller('loginController',loginController);

}());
```

Below is my loginSpec.js

```
'use strict';

describe("app module", function () {

    beforeEach(module("loginApp"));

    describe("controllerLogin", function () {
        var scope,
            controller;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller;
        }));

        it("should assign message to hello world", function () {
            controller("controllerLogin", {$scope: scope});
            expect(scope.message).toBe("Hello Galaxy");
        });
    });
});
```

Below is my galaxytest.conf.js

```
 // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'public/scripts/angular.js',
        'public/scripts/angular-mocks.js',
        'public/src/app/*.js',
        'public/app.js',
        '**/*.js',
        'test/**/*Spec.js'
    ],
```

Below is my app.js

```
//Define all the module with no dependencies.
angular.module('loginApp',[]);


//Now Define Main Module of the Application
var galaxyFrontendApp = angular.module('galaxyFrontendApp',['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','loginApp']);



galaxyFrontendApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'src/app/modules/login/views/viewLogin.html', action: 'loginApp.loginController'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
}]);
```

and Below is my index.js

```
<body>
        <div ng-view></div>



        <!-- Please refer all the javascript files here -->
        <!-- All the JS files from scripts folder -->
        <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>

        <!-- All the JS files from App folder -->
        <!-- Module Name - login -->
        <script src="src/app/modules/login/controllerLogin.js"></script>
        <script src="src/app/modules/login/directiveLogin.js"></script>




    </body>
```

Please guide me through this. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: I do not know why this does not work (it would help if you set up a plnkr.co sample) but in the controller file the line `var loginApp = angular.module('loginApp',[]);` creates a new module and the variable is not used anywhere and also the main file already defines a module with this name.

Answer (score 3):

Finally i was able to get help from @DanWahlin and he found out the problem. It was with my galaxytest.conf.js file.

```
   files: [
       "public/scripts/angular.js",
       "public/scripts/angular-mocks.js",
       "public/scripts/ui-bootstrap.js",
       "public/scripts/angular-route.js",
       "public/app.js",
       "public/src/app/modules/login/controllerLogin.js",
       "public/test/*Spec.js"
    ],
```

Thank you developers

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include the module name in the value provided to action. The module has already been loaded, and all of its controllers are in the shared namespace.

```
action: 'loginController'
```

Comment: Hi Jeff thanks for the reply, i don't think that was the problem. Still having the same problem. But i would request you to have a look at my code if you have a time and able to help me out. The code is at GitHub (https://github.com/GeekOnGadgets/AngularGalaxyUI.git)